# Gear S4 Web App Keeps Crashing on Speech Synthesis

Tags: javascript, tizen, speech-synthesis

Every time the line of code "window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);" is call the web application will crash

In order to make sure that it isn't other parts of my code causing it to crash I tried commenting it out and the app will run without issue.

The strange part is that that the "speak" will successfully execute and will say the full sentence, even though the program has crash and I am returned to the home screen

```
function Speak(){
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
msg.voice = voices[1];
msg.lang = 'en-US';
msg.rate = 1;
msg.text = VoiceText;
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

I would call the above function like;

```
VoiceText = "Hello World";
Speak();
```

I have noticed that sometimes after the crash, when the app relaunches, it will speak a few times without issue before crashing again

if someone has any idea what might be causing the issue or another client side text 2 speech they could recommend, I would be grateful, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had tried to run webapp which has exact same code you described above.
Unfortunately I couldn't observe the problem you mentioned. 
(there was no crash and tts worked well whenever Speak called.)

For more inspection, could let me know SW environment you are using?
You can get the required inform from setting -> About watch -> Software -> (Software version and Tizen version)

Comment: Hey, thank you for having a look at this :) ...
I'm running;
  Tizen Version: 4.0.0.1
  Software Version: R805FXXU1DSBA
not always but some times I will add variables in as well like....

    var state = "enabled"
    VoiceText = "Current Running State is " + state;

Irritating part is that it will crash 4 out of 5 times  on the first call, but then the 5 time it will run without any issues for a few calls of the "Speak()" function and then crash the app again when the Speak() function is called 2-3 times later... 

Please let me know how you go? :)

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code on the Galaxy Watch and Tizen Studio emulator as follows. but I couldn't find any crash.
Could you share your source code more in detail to reproduce this problem in my side? I can look into the problem further.

```
function Speak(VoiceText) {
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    msg.voice = voices[1];
    msg.lang = 'en-US';
    msg.rate = 1;
    msg.text = VoiceText;
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
        if (e.keyName == "back")
            try {
                tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
            } catch (ignore) {
            }
    });

    // Sample code
    var textbox = document.querySelector('.contents');
    textbox.addEventListener("click", function() {
        box = document.querySelector('#textbox');
        box.innerHTML = box.innerHTML == "enabled" ? "disabled" : "enabled";
        Speak("Current Running State is " + box.innerHTML);
    });
};
```